# Format POSIX in R (quantstrat)

Tags: r, quantstrat

I'm working on extracting a date from a variable: "curIndex."

Here's what the code looks likes

```
show(txntime1 <- timestamp(mktdata[curIndex+1L])[,1])

show(txntime <- strftime(txntime1, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS6'))
```

And the output is this:

```
"##------ Tue Mar 08 14:31:58 2016 ------##"

"NULL"
```

I'm working within `ruleOrderProc` of the `quantstrat` package.

The order time needs to be `POSIXlt` for the order book. Does anyone know what to do with this funky date format that I'm getting?

If so, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When all else fails, read the documentation. ;-) `?timestamp` says:

> The `timestamp` function writes a timestamp (or other message)
>   into the history and echos it to the console.  On platforms that
>   do not support a history mechanism only the console message is
>   printed.

You probably meant to call `time` or `index`. Also, the time needs to be `POSIXct` for the order book, not `POSIXlt`.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: but the ";-)" means it is *friendly* snark. :)

Comment: .@JoshuaUlrich: and the second ";-)" suggests I might have been aware. :)

Comment: Thanks, Joshua. Your input in this area throughout the pages has been beyond useful. I hope your advice in this case will lead to a solution.

Comment: Yah! `txntime <- as.POSIXct(format(time(x=mktdata[curIndex+1L][,1])))`

Comment: @EliasSimpson: you shouldn't need all that. `txntime <- index(mktdata)[curIndex+1L]` should be sufficient.